# Where can I download the voting results for UK elections?

Tags: united-kingdom, election, data-sources

Where can I download the voting results for UK elections? My question covers elections for the House of Commons, the London Assembly, the Scottish Parliament, the Welsh Parliament, the Northern Ireland Assembly, and all local elections.

Comment: Consider asking at [OpenData.SE in the "politics" tag](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/politics).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want up to date data for the most recent elections, you'll need to pick it up from a variety of different places, for example, councils have data on their own elections.  Newspapers carry some of this information, and Wikipedia will compile it

If you want the data sets from past elections gathered into one place, you can download this from the [Electoral Commission](https://www.electoralcommission.org.uk/who-we-are-and-what-we-do/elections-and-referendums/past-elections-and-referendums)  The most recent data won't be there, but what is there is final and official.

Answer (score 5):

There are a variety of places to get data from the most recent elections and from current elections, but you can get election data from the UK Parliament from this website: https://commonslibrary.parliament.uk/tag/elections-data/.